# Running .rb Ruby file

Tags: ruby, apache

What is needed to run .rb file in a web browser?

(My first day in ruby)

I have Apache server (I'm coming from PHP) with passenger. Terminal proof:

```
gundars@linuxr528:~$ apache2ctl -t -D DUMP_MODULES
passenger_module (shared)
```

ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570) [x86_64-linux]

I also have installed rails etc, Tried to make a quick app with rails and it worked fine.

Now I would like to simply open .rb file in browser, and it is prompting me to save it.
This is how it looks in my browser, the window on right side pops-up after clicking, it asks where to save it.
[image]

Entries, concerning Ruby and this file, are:

**apache2.conf:**

```
LoadModule passenger_module /home/gundars/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/passenger-3.0.11/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /home/gundars/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/passenger-3.0.11
PassengerRuby /home/gundars/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.3-p0/ruby
```

**virtual-hosts.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName tictactoe.ruby.dev
   DocumentRoot "/localhost/sandbox/RUBY/tictactoe/"
   ErrorLog /var/log/rubyonrails2.log
</VirtualHost>
```

**/etc/hosts**

```
127.0.0.1   tictactoe.ruby.dev
```

So the question - What is needed to run .rb file in a web browser?
I thought it's what passenger was for...

Comment: Ruby files do not run in a web browser. Do you mean that you want to click on a `.rb` file from the directory browsing and have the Ruby interpreter execute that file and send whatever it puts to STDOUT to the web browser instead, as plain text?

Comment: I would love to see the contents of `game.rb`; What exactly is it you're trying to output to the browser? Unless it's HTML and/or JavaScript, you're going to be disappointed.

Comment: If you understand the CGI mechanism, it is easy to write a Ruby, Perl, or even BASH app that will interface with the HTTP server. If you don't understand that then you'll need to learn it in parallel. At a minimum you should look into the [`CGI`](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/cgi/frames) module that comes with Ruby as it will give you some pre-written wheels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ruby is a server-side language. What you need is for a process to intercept your request, route it to the correct Ruby file, execute it, and send the output to your browser. Luckily, somebody has done this for you, with [Rack](http://rack.rubyforge.org/) and [Passenger](http://www.modrails.com/).

Why you would want to do this instead of working within the Rails framework is beyond me.

Comment: Well, I have one file, which should output a tic tac toe game, where I am playing against "computer". Isn't that a bit heavy, to use rails just to get one file working?

Comment: About the last sentence, well, I guess the sentence "I'm coming from php" says it all.

Comment: No, it's not heavy at all. Ruby isn't PHP, it's a general-purpose language, you need something to sit between you and the web browser. There is an entire request/response process involved that Rails handles for you. Also, what do you mean you're "outputting" a tic-tac-toe game? In text? The browser is not an interactive text terminal, that isn't going to work.

Comment: Why you would want to do this instead of working within the Rails framework is beyond me. SO before Rails and Sinatra, Wasnt Ruby used for web pages and how were they rendered to the browser

Comment: @blakroku You can't "use Ruby for web pages". Web browsers don't interpret Ruby. You can write programs that output HTML in *any language* though, and that's all Ruby is used for, in so far as its used for web pages. Rails just makes this (much) easier.

Comment: @meagar Thanks very well, i clearly understand this now

Answer (score 5):

STEPS TO RUN .rb SCRIPTS FROM APACHE:

Edit your apache configuration file (e.g., /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf). Update or create an AddHandler setting so that it includes ".rb", e.g.:

```
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .rb
```

Create your ruby script (.rb). Make sure you have a shebang (#!) pointing to your ruby interpreter.  Use the "which" command if you're not sure where ruby is.

```
#!/bin/ruby
puts "Content-type: text/html"
puts
puts "<html>"
puts "<body>"
puts "<h3>Hello</h3>"
```

Set proper ownership and execute permissions (x) on your .rb file so apache can execute it, e.g.:

```
-rwxr-x--- 1 apache apache 163 Nov 26 10:55 index.rb
```

That might be all you have to do. If your script still doesn't execute, the first troubleshooting step I would try is temporarily disabling SELinux (using setenforce 0).

Answer (score 1):

First day? Try a [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/) tutorial. It's easy to get something up and running quickly and then you can concentrate on learning the language a bit.

Comment: But first learn Ruby at least somewhat, otherwise even Sinatra will be confusing.

Comment: @theTinMan I think it's possible... I learned Rails before I learned Ruby.